# I am able to click on WebElement from List of QAFWebElements in DEBUG mode but unable to do the same in runtime mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, qaf

I am trying to select departure airport from list of airports that are appeared in a search result.

Stored all airports from the search results in QAFWebElement List Variable
Iterated through the List of Airport WebElements and Click on the Airport that matches the airport code given
my method setup appears to be correct. Not Sure why It is not selecting the airport. check the below method and also attached screenshot.

```
    @QAFTestStep(description = "User enters departure airport {dAirPort}")
    public void enterDepartureAirport(String dAirPort) {

            QAFExtendedWebDriver objDriver = getDriver();
            BookingPage bookingpage = new BookingPage();
            bookingpage.getAirPortSearchTextBox().sendKeys(dAirPort);



             List<QAFWebElement> depAirportList = objDriver.getElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"airport-serach-panel\"]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/a/span[2]"));
           
             for(QAFWebElement airPort:depAirportList) {
                     if(airPort.getText().contains(dAirPort)) {
                             System.out.println(airPort.getText().contains(dAirPort));
                             System.out.println(airPort.getText());
                             airPort.click();
                     }
             }
             Assert.assertTrue("Script failed to Select Departure Airport",bookingpage.getAirPortSearchTextBox().verifyNotPresent());
    }
```

Lets me know if anyone see an issue with the method

Comment: This test step works fine in debug mode but it not functioning in a run mode.

Answer (score 0):

possibly in normal execution it goes fast didn't wait for list to load. You can add wait for visible  or instead of list use element like this:

```
bookingpage.getAirPortSearchTextBox().sendKeys(dAirPort);

objDriver.findElement("xpath=//*[@id=\"airport-serach-panel\"]//a[contains(.,'"+dAirPort+"')]").click();
```

The best efficient way in such case is creating [custom component](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html).